# Why are sulfoxides usually stable as ylides (S charged positively and O negatively)? What's the BDE for S-O?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, stability

I can't find any info on BDE for singularly bonded S to oxygen. Moreover, I'd like to understand, why is it quite usual to find sulfoxides structure written with charge separation?

Comment: What BDE are you asking about? Energy for the diatomic molecules won't address the question regarding ylides, and BDEs in polyatomic molecules vastly depend on the neighbors and structure (there is no single value whatsoever). What exactly are you trying to compare here? Finally, I'd suggest to reformulate "*I'd like to understand*" part into a straightforward question since this makes an impression the question isn't about chemistry and is about cognition.

Comment: If you are looking for the latter set of vetted values for various compounds, check out p. 9-73 and onwards of Haynes, W. M.; Lide, D. R.; Bruno, T. J. *CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics: A Ready-Reference Book of Chemical and Physical Data*, 97th ed.; Taylor & Francis Group (CRC Press): Boca Raton, FL, **2016**. ISBN 978-1-4987-5429-3.